# Matplotlib format the scale label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have searched around SO and haven't been able to find how to format this text (I've also checked around google and the matplotlib docs)[image]

I'm currently creating a figure and then adding 4 subplots in a 2x2 matrix format so I'm trying to scale down all the text:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax1.tick_params(labelsize='xx-small')
ax1.set_title(v, fontdict={'fontsize':'small'})
ax1.hist(results[v], histtype='bar', label='data', bins=bins, alpha=0.5)
ax1.hist(results[v+'_sim'], histtype='bar', label='truth', bins=bins, alpha=0.8)
ax1.legend(loc='best', fontsize='x-small')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parameters before plot:

```
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = "xx-small"
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = "xx-small"
```